# Which tense should I use: "I was" / "I had been" / "I were"?

Tags: wish

Which one is grammatically correct : I wish **I was born** in 1900 / I wish **I had been born** in 1900 / I wish **I were born** in 1900 ? And why ?

Comment: I think the second. You are not wishing to be born, but wishing you were in the situation of having been born in 1900.

Comment: @KateBunting care to elaborate in an answer? I know you probably didn't post one because it would be too short, but comments under the question are hardly the best of places for the answers to the question.

Answer (score 1):

*Had been*.

Traditionally *were* is used for non-past irrealis (counterfactual) clauses: *I wish I were able to leave my house now*,

and *had been* for past irrealis clauses: *I wish I had been able to leave my house last week*.

However, the use of *were* is declining, and many people don't use it, or don't use it in speech, but substitute *was*.

Traditionally *was* (like *is*) is used for realis (non-counterfactual) conditionals like *If he was there, I didn't see him.* (i.e. I don't know if he was there or not, so he could have been), and contrasts with irrealis *were*. But this is irrelevant for *wish*, because its meaning is necessarily irrealis. So people who use *were* in conditionals also use it with *wish*, and people who use *was* use it in both places. But this is not directly relevant to your question, because it is necessarily a past irrealis, and so has to be *had been*.